# Any reasons to not attach listeners to widgets in a Fragment's view in Fragment.onCreateView()?

Tags: android, listener, lifecycle, fragment

Must I add listeners (e.g. `OnClickListener`) to views in `Fragment.onActivityCreated()`, or can I safely do so in `Fragment.onCreateView()`?

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use onActivityCreated() as this method is called after onCreateView and all the views and the Context has been instantiated

Comment: But if the Fragment doesn't access any views outside of itself, why wait till onActivityCreated()?  Also, the Context is the enclosing Activity, and that's already created by the time onCreateView() is called.  So, back to my original question...

Comment: Makes sense ..its just that onActivityCreated is safer